# ajax cant find id in dataTable if its included in the datatable

Tags: ajax, jsf

I dont know if im stupid or if im getting something completely wrong. Im trying for a few days now to render a specific panelGrid in a Form with ajax. I tried different things to give ajax the id to render but it always fails with :

f:ajax contains an unknown id 'idxx' - cannot locate it in the context of the component xxx

When i check my html code its exactly the id my panelGrid has. So im wondering why this is happening.

This is my jsf code:

```
<h:form id="id" rendered="#{classX.isSearchResultFound()" >
<h:panelGrid id="someotherGrid" rendered="#{classX.searchResultDetails > 0}">
...
</h:panelGrid>
<div id="resultWrapper>
     <h:dataTable>
        <h:panelGrid id="resultGrid">
            <h:column>
              <h:commandButton styleClass="additionalAttributesClickTarget">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" render="#{component.parent.clientId}" listener="#{classX.toggleAdditionalInfos(searchResultsInList)}" onevent="onToggleResult" />
              </h:commandButton>
           </h:column>
        </h:panelGrid>
     </h:dataTable>
    </div>
 </h:form>
```

so i basically want to render one row in the table which contains some nested things again. When i look on the server logs the the error shows exactly the id of the panelgrid in the complete form so :

```
formid-tableid-0-resultGrid
```

I dont see why it cant find the id when its obviously there and in the same form? maybe i oversee something and this is a stupid question but i would be very happy if someone could explain my error or if this concept is wrong.

Comment: I do not see any component like `<h:table>` in the standard JSF namespace `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html` (or `http://java.sun.com/jsf/html` before JSF 2.2). It is `<h:dataTable>` instead.

Comment: yes sorry you are correct. Changed it but thats just a detail.. it was a more generous question anyways and the code is a example.

Comment: An `<h:dataTable>`, in turn is an iterating JSF component. It is not just like an `<h:panelGrid>`. You need to iterate over a collection somehow using that `<h:dataTable>` in conjunction with its `value` and `var` attributes. Or drop the given `<h:dataTable>` and choose, if necessary a different component like another `<h:panelGrid>`, if iterating over a collection is not the case - is not required at all.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more in detail what you mean with iterate with its value and var? To get the id to render? I mean as i said i got the right id but it says it cant find it... im wondering if its a bug

Comment: If you have a collection (like a `java.util.List<T>`) in a managed bean (`private List<T> list`) with a getter (and a setter, if needed) and if that collection contains 10 items, you can iterate over the collection using an `<h:dataTable>` such as `<h:dataTable var="row" value="#{bean.list}"...>` and you can use the value of `var` (`row`) as a reference to each item/element in the list inside the table to display a list of 10 items. If you do not do that, the `<h:dataTable>` will not be rendered i.e if it is not the case, just drop the `<h:dataTable>` and use another component of your need.

Comment: Not each tag in jsf results in a component. And you can only update components. So make sure what you want to update IS a component? Individual rows in datatables are not. Omnifaces has an extension to achieve what you want. Or at least I think want you want http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Ajax

Comment: Hi, since i want to update a <h:panelGrid> this should def be a component or at least i know that it can be updated by ajax. omnifaces actually seems to have the possibilty to render it from server side. But thats not really what i want. It seems like im running into this problem since im using 2.1.28 and this was never fixed as it seems ... https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1834

Answer (score 0):

I know did a workaround and set the id on server.

```
partialViewContext.getRenderIds().add(renderId);
```

When i do that adding the exact same id he actually does what hes supposed to and renders the part. So the id is only not found when i add it to the render attribute in f:ajax. Seems like this is the reason since it was never fixed:

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1834